# Laravel 7 App is failing to upload to Heroku cloud service

Tags: mysql, laravel, heroku, cloud

I have a problem with uploading my laravel app to heroku, it gives this error. I do not know what the problem is really?

Ive tried everything, the database is working the env file has correct parameters as well

```
heroku remote: In Exception.php line 18: remote: remote: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused remote:
 remote: remote: In PDOConnection.php line 38: remote: remote: 
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused remote: remote: remote:
 Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
```

Comment: are you doing a query in a service provider?

Comment: @lagbox yes  it is

Comment: what command was it running? `composer install`?